# Which question tag is correct: “do / don't / have / haven't they?”

Tags: tag-questions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

> "The children hardly have problems waking up early for school, _______?"
>
> 1. do they
> 2. don't they
> 3. have they
> 4. haven't they

I am not sure which is the right [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question), also called *Question tag* in BrEng.

Am I confident and only asking someone to confirm my statement?

> 1. The children hardly **have** problems[…], **do** they?

Am I uncertain and want to know if I am wrong?

> 2. The children **hardly have** problems […], **don't** they?

Should I repeat the same verb in the subordinate clause?

> 3. Thee children hardly **have** problems[…], **have** they?

Or should the question tag be negative because the statement is positive?

> 4. The children hardly **have** problems[…], **haven't** they?

I find question tags very confusing, as each of the four solutions appear to make sense to me.

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta at https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/request-question-reopen-and-or-explanation-for-closevotes If the OP reads that thread, s/he will find several suggestions for how to improve this question, and others will find ideas about how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 3):

OP's alternatives #2 and #4 are completely unacceptable in the cited context. The basic rule is that "tag" questions always negate the preceding "assertion", but in this case, the underlying assertion (the possibility that the children have problems) is already effectively negated by ***hardly*** (implying either they don't *really* have problems, or their problems are too trivial to count).

It's worth noting that the "internal negation" of the initial assertion would be the same if we replaced ***hardly*** by ***rarely, seldom, never, do not,*** or similar. Those are all "negative polarity" constructions, which cause any associated tag question to be in "positive" form.

As to the choice between ***have / do they**?* - this is effectively a matter of style / personal preference. The "logical" choice is ***have they**?* because it echoes the verb in the preceding assertion. But *in practice*, for reasons I can't readily explain, native speakers tend to use ***do they**?* far more often in such contexts.

Comment: The tag question "have they" should repeat the *auxiliary* "have". In the sentence: *The'**ve** hardly **had** a wink of sleep, **have they**?* The auxiliary in "have had" is used.

Comment: An "unfortunate" example, because it includes two different uses of ***to have*** (auxiliary "perfect" ***'ve*** *and* "possessive" as in *They only **had** a brief nap*). Your observation might be better illustrated by *They **have** hardly slept, **have they**?*

Comment: ...where if we discard ***hardly***, the initial assertion *isn't* "negated", so the tag question *will* be in the negative: *They **have** slept, **haven't** they?* And for a "non-auxiliary" use of ***to have***, it's *We **have** money, **haven't** we?* (but more idiomatically for many/most speakers, *We **have** money, **don't** we?*)

Comment: "(hardly) have problems" does not use the Present Perfect constructions, which is the point I was making. I chose a PP constructions *have had a wink* to show the OP the difference between the auxiliary and the main verb.

Comment: I would be very surprised to hear an American say "have they" where "have" is not an auxiliary.

Comment: Perhaps in BrE the most common form would be "*We'**ve got** money, **haven't** we?*" But I'm not criticising the answer, I upvoted actually.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Maybe we should call that "got-support" (along the lines of "do-support"), but I don't think I've ever heard that designation. I have the impression many people think "got-support" is predominantly a feature of *American* Engish, but [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We%27ve+got+money%2CWe+have+got+money%2CWe+have+money&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) and [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We%27ve+got+money%2CWe+have+got+money%2CWe+have+money&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) charts look much the same to me.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney: A long time ago, some Brits would ask *Have you a light? [for my cigarette]*, stereotypically contrasted with the American versions ***Do you have / Have you got** a light?* But the remaining smokers both sides of the pond today are probably more likely to settle for just *[You] **Got** a light?*

Comment: Oh! I have always assumed that was still common among Brits.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney: Back in Shakespeare's day we were all asking each other things like [“**Have you a** ruffian that will swear, drink, dance, Revel the night, rob, murder, and commit. The oldest sins the newest kind of ways?”](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9508815-have-you-a-ruffian-that-will-swear-drink-dance-revel#:~:text=%E2%80%9CHave%20you%20a%20ruffian%20that%20will%20swear%2C%20drink%2C%20dance,the%20newest%20kind%20of%20ways%3F%E2%80%9D) before we discovered cigarettes and needed to ask strangers for the wherewithal to set fire to them! (But we mostly speak "American" today! :)

Comment: The auxiliary here is "do", not "have": "*The children **do** have problems*". "***Do** the children have problems?" This "have" is the main verb because it has a direct object, "problems", and there's no past participle, so it's not a perfect construction.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney  I also believed "got" was more common among Brits.  On the other hand, there's also (colloquially) a form with "got" but without "have" - "We got money", "You got this" - which definitely feels more American to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have always heard the traditional contrast to be between British "Have you (got) a light?" and American "Do you have a light?".  Oxford seems to agree, at least in part: "a traditional view is that *have got* is chiefly British". ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/have )

Comment: FWIW the OED shows that "got"-support predates the development of AmE (though quite a few features later considered American do, but I just don't agree that this is one of them), and is first found in Shakespeare (1616) ("Fie, th'art a churle, ye haue got a humour there / Does not become a man").  Jonathan Swift, 1738: "Miss, you have got my Handkerchief; pray, let me have it."  J. Eachard, 1670: "They have got ... such a peculiar Method of Text-dividing."